# parse javascript object returned from ajax as html

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, parsing

Result (`data`) looks like this:

```
<tr>
   <td>
      Something...
   </td>
</tr>

<div id="paging">1, 2, 3... </div>
```

This is ajax

```
...
dataType: "html",
success: function(data) {
    parse data...    
    $('#myDiv1').html(data1);
    $('#myDiv2').html(data2);
}
...
```

Is it possible to parse `data` so that `data1` contains table row(s) and `data2` contains `div#paging` content?

Thanks in advance,

Ilija

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try..

```
var data1 = $(data).find('tr');
var data2 = $(data).find('div#paging');
```

edit:

as Guffa, mentioned in below comments, you cannot parse it if the html is broken in structure... but I suspected you got more than that codes... anyway, [here's a demo](http://jsbin.com/aviso3/edit)

Comment: when I alert data1 or data2 I only see [object Object]

Comment: if you want to try to alert, do for example `alert(data1.html());`

Comment: @Guffa - what do you mean by doesn't work?... isn't this ajax result?

Comment: @Reigel: There is no `table` tag around the td, so the code won't be parsed correctly.

Comment: @Guffa - ahhh I assumed he got more codes than that... okay I will update my answer... thanks...

Comment: @ile - please take note that there are many li... so you might need to iterate each...

Comment: I see... obviously I need to have correct syntax so that elements can be selected.
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

As the HTML code is not complete, it can't simply be parsed by the browser. You have to parse it manually.

For example:

```
var match = /(<tr>.+</tr>)\s*(<div.+</div>)/.exec(data)
var data1 = match[1];
var data2 = match[2];
```

Comment: -1 for parsing html with a regex, while ignoring the selector engine.

Comment: @Agos: As I said in the answer, that **doesn't work**. As the HTML is not complete, you **can't** parse it that way, and thus can **not** use the selector engine.